# How to merge the first row of a table created by VBScript

Tags: vba, vbscript, ms-word

I have a VBScript which creates a table. It loops through an array and inserts the information into a table in a Word document.

```
'Create new word doc
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

objWord.Visible = True
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add()
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

objSelection.Font.Name = "Verdana"
objSelection.Font.Size = "12"
objSelection.TypeText sFileSelected
objSelection.TypeParagraph()

objSelection.Font.Name = "Verdana"
objSelection.Font.Size = "12"

Set objRange = objSelection.Range
Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set objTF = objFSO.opentextfile(logPathAndFileName)
strAll = objTF.readall
arrVar = Split(strAll, vbNewLine)
numcols = 3

objDoc.Tables.Add objRange, UBound(arrVar) - LBound(arrVar) + 1, numcols
Set objTable = objDoc.Tables(1)

For lngrow = LBound(arrVar) To UBound(arrVar)
    If lngrow > 0 Then
        arrVar2 = Split(arrVar(lngrow), vbTab)
        For lngcol = LBound(arrVar2) To UBound(arrVar2)
            objTable.Cell(lngrow, lngcol + 1).Range.Text = arrVar2(lngcol)
            If lngrow = 1 Then
                Set myRange = objDoc.Range(objTable.Cell(2, 1).Range.Start,objTable.Cell(4, 1).Range.End) 
                myRange.Merge
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```

This produces a table like this:
[image]

What I would like to do now is merge the top row: DATABASE MODIFICATIONS. How can I merge the row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code for merging whole row (first row in this sample line):

```
objTable.Rows(1).Cells.Merge
```

**Edit:** if you need to merge some cells in the row you could do it in this way (by selection first and last cells- area in between will be merged):

```
'for 2nd row, cells from 2 to 3
objTable.Cell(2, 2).Merge objTable.Cell(2, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks this works. Is there an easy way to change the text style for a row too? Specifically making the text bold for the first row, if I am not using the auto styling.

Comment: To make 1st row bold use this code: `objTable.Rows(1).Range.Bold = true`

Comment: Thanks was waiting to find out on the bold information.